# Get runtime error with Sharepoint 365 modern experience in C# code

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am trying to access the lists in a SharePoint site, I am using Sharepoint 365 with the modern experience.

My problem is that I get timeout error on the line

```
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I used this link as reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#basic-operations-with-the-sharepoint-net-client-object-model

This is my code:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https:siteurl"))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

    foreach (char c in "mypwd".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("myuser", passWord);

    Web web = clientContext.Web;

    // Retrieve all lists from the server.
    // For each list, retrieve Title and Id.
    clientContext.Load(web.Lists,
                         lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title,
                                                list => list.Id));
           
    // Execute query.
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    // Enumerate the web.Lists.
    foreach (List list in web.Lists)
    {
        label1.Text = label1.Text + ", " + list.Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a large dataset?

Comment: no, I have few lists with 2 items